# Golang setting a simple json string

Tags: go

What is the easy way to construct a simple json to send to client http response

How about this

```
json.Marshal(`{}`)
```

Is there a better way to send am simple json object to http response?

Thanks for help

Comment: That doesn't create a json object, that creates a quoted string containing open and close braces. Your input of `{}` already is an empty json object.

Comment: You can use json.Encoder to serialize a Go object and write it out as a stream of bytes: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Encoder.Encode

Answer (score 1):

`"{}"` is already a string and valid JSON, so you don't need to call `json.Marshal`.

If you wanted to use `json.Marshal`, you could use something that would render out the same way, like a literal `map[string]interface{}{}`.

```
    j, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(j))
    }
```

For a full example see https://go.dev/play/p/GI4JlW9hu1q